# AngularJS $uibModal Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

Could you please let me know what is wrong with my code? I get the initial HTML page, but when I click on "Open", nothing happens. Not even the console logs an error, or any other change.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('carApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

ctrl.js

```
app.controller('carCtrl', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {
    $http.get('jobs.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;

        $scope.open = function() {

            var modalContent = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'careersTpl.html',
                controller : modalContentCtrl,
                resolve: {
                    items: function() {
                        return $scope.data;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
});

var modalContentCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.data.specs
  };
};
```

JSON:

```
{
   "specs":[
      {
         "job-title":"TITLE",
         "job-apply":"applink",
         "job-body":"JOB BODY"
      }
   ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="car-up">
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="careersTpl.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        </div>   
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</p>
        </div>
     </script>    
     <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open</button>
</div>
```

I'm new to AngularJS, but I have linked the `app.js` and `ctrl.js`... thanks.

EDIT: after I've placed `ng-controller="carCtrl"` in the html file, I receive this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstance
>   O/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:6:412
>   db/n.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:43:84
>   d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:40:344
>   db/V<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:43:144
>   d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:40:344
>   e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:41:78
>   h/<.invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:41:163
>   gf/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:89:397
>   resolveSuccess@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:4422:34
>   e/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:130:409
>   vf/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:103
>   vf/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:142:165
>   vf/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:145:399
>   Lc[b]https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:274:444
>   Sf@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:37:31
>   Rf/d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:36:486

Comment: do a console.log in your open function to see if it is firing

Comment: why you had defined `$scope.open ` inside `$http.get` call `success` function.. does that ajax call get succeed?

Comment: did you  informed the controller in the html ? like ng-controller="controllerName"

Comment: Nope. nothing. Even the data is not getting logged.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: post the code for carCtrl

Comment: It is pasted already above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find working demo

```js
angular.module('carApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
var app = angular.module('carApp');
app.controller('carCtrl', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {
  //$http.get('jobs.json').success(function(data) {//Uncomment
  //$scope.data = data; Uncomment 

  //Remove below line from code when you are using this in your project
  $scope.data = {
    "specs": [{
      "job-title": "TITLE",
      "job-apply": "applink",
      "job-body": "JOB BODY"
    }]
  }

  $scope.open = function() {

      var modalContent = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'careersTpl.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        resolve: {
          items: function() {
            return $scope.data;
          }
        }
      })
    }
    //});//Uncomment
});

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($uibModalInstance, items, $scope) {
  $scope.data = items;
  console.log($scope.data);
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.data.specs
  };

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="carApp">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.0.js"></script>

  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="carCtrl" class="modal-demo">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="careersTpl.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.specs">
          <span>Title: {{v["job-title"]}}<br/> </span>
          <span>Link: {{v["job-apply"]}}<br/> </span>
          <span>Body: {{v["job-body"]}}<br/> </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </script>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's working but please make adjust it with to work with `$http.get('jobs.json')`... Thanks.

Comment: @eric There is no option in code snippet to add new file. So I won't be able to add jobs.json file. So I had to added json manually like this.

But to help you out I had added //Uncomment after the line which you have to uncomment while  you use this code in your environment.

Hope this may help you

Comment: I get $ctrl is not defined. How to I bind it with the controller in this template? It works without $ctrl fine, but let's say I want it to work with $ctrl.

Comment: Where have you used $ctrl, In which file or controller?
Please make sure have you added controllerAs: '$ctrl', option in  $uibModal.open.

Comment: Oh, figured out. I didn't use quotations. Done. thanks.

Comment: And if it isn't too much. Can you explain the (k,v) and [] in the html please? I don't understand this.

Comment: If you want to iterate over object properties we have to use (k,v) where k means key and v means Value. 
Here is helpful link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the controller like this outside,

```
app.controller('modalContentCtrl ', function($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.data.specs
  };

}
```

Comment: Now I get this error: modalContentCtrl is not defined